# android build gradle error (android 3.1.3) ? Connection timed out: connect

Tags: android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, build.gradle, jcenter

my gradle build Could not GET

'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'.166 INTERNAL CALLS

'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'

my build gradle

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
    all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

   repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
 }

allprojects {
   repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Gradle wrapper propriety

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have antvirus on you PC? Try to switch off it..
I had the same issue:

> Could not get resource
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.1.3/compiler-3.1.3.pom

I have Kasperskiy Internet Secirity on my PC. I was able to buld project just after disable it and go to File-> Invalidate cache and restart. Then project was builded successfully. 
Then I enable KIS back and can build project without issues.

Comment: Think you.. but why is that happening @Vlad

Comment: I think there is issue with certificate: https://gyazo.com/295b3321ff9048e4273e813f9a14871f

Comment: In my case I had defined the true proxy in the Android Studio settings, but the build did not work telling 'connection timed out: connection' when it was at stage applying build.gradle. Finally I run Sync 'Project With Gradle Files' from File menu and it showed a dialog asking to use the proxy which I had set in the Android Studio settings, for gradle and I confirmed that dialog. Then it worked.  Also notice to add Android Studio in Windows Firewall if it is not there (If you have two AS versions see details to check which one is in FWall list).